# longtable: Keeping some cells together on the same page

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I'm using longtable in my CV to list work experience, so it can continue over multiple pages. However I like to keep some rows together, such as employer and job title, is there a way how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `\\*` at line ends for such tabular lines